# Validating user input on client and server

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have regular expression in jquery for "Valid values alphabets, numbers, spaces, hyphens and underscores" as [a-z0-9_,-\s]+$, it works fine.

JQUery function:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("onlyalphanumeric", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9_,\-\s]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Valid values are alphabets, numbers, spaces, hyphens and underscores");
```

If I try to use the same in MVC 4 model as mentioned below, it doesn't work.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-z0-9_,\-\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Valid values are alphabets, numbers, spaces, hyphens and underscores")]
public string NickName { get; set; }
```

Comment: What string are you testing? Also, the javascript regex has the ignore-case flag on but the .NET regex does not account for the capital letters.

Comment: You quite likely need to add `A-Z` to account for uppercase letters.

Comment: @DavidHaney or the `i` modifier.

Comment: The .NET `i` modifier would not work with the javascript regex. The rules don't work the same way for both languages unfortunately.